# How to use getDate() in h2 as like sql server

Tags: h2, getdate

I'm testing the already developed application through Junit test cases, uses **SQL server** in production but while executing test cases we used embedded **h2 database**. 
And some of the SQL server specifications are not working in h2 (ex: `conditional queries`, `getDate()`, `DATEPART`,..........) can anyone help me how to tackle this kind issues further in my **JUnit testing** with h2 DB

```
SQL SERVER: select * from getDate() -: 2006-12-30 00:38:54.840
h2 DB :     select * from getDate() -: 2006-12-30
```

While executing test cases that scripts are executing in h2 database and as a part of logic, I'm parsing the value from `getdate()` into SimpleDate format of `2006-12-30 00:38:54.840`, and I'm getting parse exception that `2006-12-30` couldn't parse.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

To use getDate in H2, simply run the following query before using a query with getDate()

```
drop alias if exists getDate;

create alias getDate as '
    java.util.Date getDate() {
        return new java.util.Date();
    }
    ';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use User-Defined Functions and Stored Procedures built in H2 database.